# rake db:migrate is aborted when migrating gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-votable

im sure this is a simple enough error i just cant figure it out.
I'm installing ryanto/acts_as_votable gem and i'm getting the following issue.
There are issues similar but I cant find any fixes that can be implemented before the rake db:migrate

Gemfile:

```
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
```

then I'm

```
rails generate acts_as_votable:migration
rake db:migrate
```

Then the rake is being aborted and i'm getting this message

```
davemc:~/workspace/newsroom (rating) $ rake db:migrate
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is outdated/buggy.
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is: 2.3.0 (buggy). Recommendation: upgrade to 
2.3.1.
RubyDep: WARNING: (To disable warnings, 
see:http://github.com/e2/ruby_dep/wiki/Disabling-warnings )
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `resources' for main:Object
/home/ubuntu/workspace/newsroom/config/routes.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `block in load_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `load_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:18:in `reload!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in updater'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:81:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:42:in `updater'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:31:in `execute_if_updated'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:128:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/newsroom/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top 
(required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top 
(required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :users
     root to: "posts#index"
 end
  resources :posts #do
     #member do
    #  put "like" => "posts#upvote"
   #   put "dislike" => "posts#downvote"

 #end
```

#end

The new error :

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations  
anceled:

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please 
specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

  class ActsAsVotableMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
```

Comment: Please add your routes file here.

Comment: It sounds that your gem would like your ruby version to be upgraded to 2.3.1 : `RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is outdated/buggy.
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is: 2.3.0 (buggy). Recommendation: upgrade to 
2.3.1.`

Comment: Read the error message carefully, so you ll gate your answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks a mill.my routes file is added above, i #out the code for the gem as its not migrated yet. The last time the gem as updated was 3 years ago so I assume the new ruby wouldn't make a difference, am I wrong in that?

Comment: have you run `bundle install` ?

Comment: yes I have ran bundle install

Comment: @LiffeyD correct your routes file. Its outside the block. Check my posted answer

Comment: Correct, I have already noticed the error in the log that's why to tell you to add the file here. And finally, you got answered.

Comment: Now you just have to go through all act_as_votable migration files and add the version they were generated at ([4.2])

For example:

`class AddMissingIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]`

There is an issue and a pull request open to fix this, but in the meantime you have to add it yourself.

https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/issues/142

Comment: @epergo That worked Thanks a million, you are a gent.

Answer (score 1):

Your routes file is incorrect.

Correct code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: "posts#index"
  resources :posts
end
```

Comment: Thanks a million i'm now getting an error saying i need to state the version it was written for but I can access it because it wont migrate it. I will writhe the message in the codebox above

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your routes file,You have added `resources :posts` outside of `Rails.application.routes.draw` block.

```
MyAppName::Application.routes.draw do
   #resources
end
```

Comment: Hi, I amended my routes file with your code above, thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to my c9.io if it helps  https://ide.c9.io/davemc/project-paperclip

Answer (score 1):

> NoMethodError: undefined method `resources' for main:Object

You have `resources :posts` outside of the `block`. Put that inside

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: "posts#index"
  resources :posts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix I had to go to db>migrate>'file i was migrating' and add

```
class AddMissingIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
```